document.write not working when pulling code from online
I'm making a game using emulatorjs and ruffle. It is supposed to be in a single file that can be downloaded and be run locally. I am trying to make another file that people can download that will auto-update. It works, but a lot of the scripts aren't working. Here is the code:
<script>
    fetch('https://trapjawws.github.io/funnyemulatorjs/index.html')
    .then(function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            // status "OK"
            case 200:
                return response.text();
            // status "Not Found"
            case 404:
                throw response;
        }
    })
    .then(function (template) {
        document.write(template);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // "Not Found"
        alert(response.statusText);
    });
</script>

That code doesn't work. It's supposed to look like this: working one, the search bar loads, and the pokedex loads. It's main features are: having a search bar in the dropdown menu, loading games, and having a (working) Pokedex.
but instead it looks like this: search bar and Pokedex do not load, the search bar is not loading, and the Pokedex is not loading
On the one that doens't work, the built in Pokedex doesn't work, and the search bar doesn't work. These both pull assets from online, so yeah, that's probably important.
I have been playing around with it but it still hasn't been working. I found this site: https://toolki.com/en/html2js that does what I want perfectly, but I went through the site's code and I couldn't find the script that converts the code, because I want it to do it automatically when it pulls the code.
Basically, my goal is to have it pull the code from my Github site and write that code to the file, that can be downloaded and run locally.
Also, here is the code for the working one, if you guys wanted it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TrapjawwS/funnyemulatorjs/main/index.html
By the way, I'm new to HTML and js, so sorry if I'm making any stupid mistakes. :(

You fell for document.write: don't use it. It clears the page when you run it after the document has loaded. Or is that your intention?

"It's supposed to look like this:... but instead it looks like this": what is the difference?

"doesn't work" is not a helpful problem statement. Please tell us what is supposed to happen, and what happens instead.

Yeah, it is supposed to clear the page. The difference between the 2 images, is the one that doesn't work, the searcch bar is not there, and the second difference, that is not included in the image, the Pokedex does not load :(

"the searchbar is not there": to me the two images look the same, except for a size/offset difference.

document.write doesn't make sense here. It does not give you anything that can be downloaded. Really it sounds like the user should just navigate to https://trapjawws.github.io/funnyemulatorjs/index.html and save that page.

I tried to do this in a single file as a fun little thing to do, like a challenge that I could learn from, which part of the challenge for myself is having a portable file that auto-updates whenever I add something new.

You cannot have an auto-updating file if you're loading it from the filesystem into the browser, as the web page is not allowed to write to the filesystem. document.write has nothing to do with this. Your best bet is a portable self-updating web server executable, or doing something with a service worker and the cache api to make an offline-enabled app. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Guides/Offline_and_background_operation

no like it doesn't re-write the code, it just pulls the code from online and writes it to the page. I would also prefer it to just be a static HTML file. But thanks.

document.write(template);

The question is... what exactly are you writing to with document.write? What is "document"?
Just in case, here's how to properly use document.write()
var W = window.open();  // create a new window

W.document.open(); // create a write-stream to this window

W.document.write('<div>sample html</div>'); // add some HTML

W.document.close(); // close it off

You’re not meant to overwrite your own document or you’re doing it wrong, and you’re not meant to write to a file on disk… well you can’t anyway!
The idea is to create a new write stream and fill it with whatever it is you need regardless of the number of sources.
